# Can you gzip a blob after uploading / while it is in the Azure Storage Account?

Tags: azure, azure-data-lake, azure-blob-storage

So I am incrementally loading (chunking) data to an Azure blob, due to low memory in the Azure Function. Everything is going fine, but I want to do gzip on that blob data, once all the data is in place (i.e. stored within the container of the storage account). Is this possible to send an HTTP request or something for Azure to handle that gzip operation INSTEAD of me downloading the full data again to do the gzip operation, as that would entirely defeat the purpose and cause me to run back into the low memory issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer, no this is not possible. Azure blob storage does not provide any such compute operations for you. You need to download the files, run compute (such as zipping) on them and re-upload.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: if this answers your question, please mark it as Accepted

Comment: I'm going to give more time for others to provide interesting feedback. I'll accept once a week has passed.